# PostgresQL select row where value is inside an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."test" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "game_ids" integer[],
    CONSTRAINT "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

INSERT INTO "test" ("id", "game_ids") VALUES
(1, '{5,6,7}'),
(2, '{5,12,18}'),
(3, '{12,13,18}'),
(4, '{14,22,23}');
```

And I would like to query so that I get all rows where the `game_ids` column contains the value 12.

So something like `SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids CONTAIN 12;`

I have heard about the `ANY` and the `@>` operators, but they don't seem to work. I get Syntax error on all of these tries:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE ANY game_ids = 12;  // Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANY"

SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids @> [12]; // Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids @> 12; // Error in query: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] @> integer

SELECT * FROM test WHERE 12 = ANY game_ids; // Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "game_ids"

SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids >@ [12]; // Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
```

does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `12 = ANY (game_ids)` needs parenthesis. `game_ids @> ARRAY[12]`  needs a constructor, or `game_ids @> '{12}'` (maybe `game_ids @> '{12}'::int[]`)

Comment: geez, sometimes the solution is so simple. Thank you so much @Bergi , both options work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ANY` operator requires parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 12 = ANY( game_ids );
```

To construct an array for the `@>` operator, use

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids @> ARRAY[12];
-- or
SELECT * FROM test WHERE game_ids @> '{12}';
```